# What might be the reasons for downvotes on these two questions?

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations, asking-questions, down-votes

Both the following questions asked by me contain one downvote each

[Which scriptures say that eating rice mixed with milk at night increases one's life span while eating curd at night decreases it?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11094/which-scriptures-say-that-eating-rice-mixed-with-milk-at-night-increases-ones-l)

[Which scripture says that during eclipse all water become pure like Ganges water?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11093/which-scripture-says-that-during-eclipse-all-water-become-pure-like-ganges-water)

Both are supported by sources & both are very valid Hinduism related questions.

I'm not quite sure but possibly these declarations might be present in some Dharama Sutras (like Parasara or Manu's) or might very well be present in some  Puranas as well. Well then, where they are present was the object of my questions.

Now, if i don't know the reasons for the downvotes I'll hesitate to post further questions.

Usefullness or Uselessness can't be a reason because I can see many meritless and absolutely useless questions are being posted here on a regular basis. But then, these are very subjective.

What are the other (possible) reasons for the downvotes?

Comment: Ok.Btw can moderators know which users up/downvote a question or answer?

Comment: No, Even moderators can't see who (up|down)votes a (question|answer). [Refer this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82004/316272).

Comment: But i see some similarity between both questions- Both have same source and in both you are asking `scriptural basis for these claims`. Just a observation.

Comment: @Sandeep Yes, both questions have the same source.I asked in separate questions coz asking too many questions in one question isn't allowed.Also both questions are distinct and not related to each other.So i had to make two separate questions.If i don't know the reasons i may ask similar questions in future too.

Comment: @Rickross Overall, you have more upvote then downvote, so you didn't need to worry at all. Even i did checked your profile and you didn't got any targeted downvote yet.

Comment: @ankit shrama Thank you.But i feel someone is targeting me for no reasons .Anyways it will be nice if i can know precisely why the down votes were casted.Because right now i'm completely clueless.If i know only then i can be more careful while asking in future :banghead:

Comment: @Rickross The tools i have, didn't detected any anomaly yet. And to be frank i am not fan of any of this two question either but i didn't downvoted them, so can't say the reason. Maybe someone else can come up with reason.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Forget about these 2 questions for the time being.Can u tell me why the downvote in the following question? It seems the vote was casted at about the same time when the other downvote was casted on my  hinduism question.:http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/500/are-partial-answers-considered-valid-answers/503?noredirect=1#comment1631_503

Comment: @Rickross Downvoting on meta means different, downvote means disagreement with the proposal and doesn't means question is wrong. Nothing to be taken personal here.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Agreed ,but i was not proposing anything .i did not want to initiate a discussion.I just wanted to know whether partial answers are accepted or not.I actually wanted answers specifically from moderators and that is exactly why i selected urs answer as the best one.So still why the downvote then?

Comment: @Rickross My suggestion: Don't bother posting/asking about downvotes on meta :) There can be 100 different reasons, see my answer [here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/429/2995). If you do ask as in this case, you will end up getting answers from people who have not downvoted your questions or answers. So does it really serve your purpose?

Comment: @sv i had asked primarily because i'm new to this site.Yet to be fully acquainted with all its rules.

Comment: @Rickross There can be many reason, maybe downvoter seems the post pointless or of no use, we can't say definite reason, only downvoter can clear it. Until its not serial downvote , there is no need for worry.

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't downvoted any of those 2 Qs + this Q, probably I can say in neutral tone what went wrong. BTW, I have in fact upvoted your Q1 & this Q, as I find it good. You may also add [How do scriptures describe ideal Sanyasi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11173/1049), which is luckily upvoted.

### Problem

... is in nature of the pattern:

> ***Which/What/How* scriptures say ...**
>   --> You are not really asking anything!

When some people ask such Q, they are just asking for "information" instead of "knowledge". Ofcourse people can have correct/incorrect information/knowledge, but at least in case of "knowledge" one has a chance to be creative and put own thoughts. In case of "information", you are just asking them to Google about the claims made in Q.

Scriptures are for backup & reference, not the primary thing. Interesting part is how one interprets rightly or wrongly.
For example, how would you feel if I have forgotten my way and ask you:

> Which map among Google/Bing/OSM/Yahoo will give me the shortest path?
>   vs
>   What is the shortest path?

Or, if I am thirsty and come to you:

> I am aware of water, coke, pepsi. Which drink will ease my thirst?
>   vs
>   Can you plz give me something to drink?

You may find above analogies stupid, but that's what many of us feel when someone asks such Q.
**Are you concerned about "who said it?" or "what is the truth?"**

### Self Contradiction

This can be a secondary reason, but putting for the records.
In above kind of Q, all the claims are listed with probable scripture link. And then it's asked "*which scripture?*". Some people may feel that, if you have already some scriptural references then why are you asking for 2nd set.

Personally I feel such Qs are meant for showcasing knowledge as there is no blog facility in SE sites. The asker may not really want any answer!

What I described is just 1 possible perspective, upon which you shouldn't be judgemental. There might be different reasons too.

---

Regarding downvote for this Q, is (little weird) meta.SE style to show disagreement. Reputation is not changed with votes here.

Comment: It seems im at the wrong place.I'll have to reconsider many a times before asking my next question then.Your answer is somewhat helpful though.BTw Q3 is already downvoted. :)Noticed just now.

Comment: @Rickross,You need not pass a judgement to refrain from asking Q, just based on my answer. Whichever Qs you have listed are downvoted by different people, i.e. there is no targeted downvoting, as pointed by the Mod. What I expressed in this answer is just a possible problem. Having said that, I have commented as "Good Q" in 1 of your post and answered your last post. So I am not against it. In fact, I had also asked [one question](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11000/1049), which was asking for scriptures. Now I have edited it, even though my reason for asking scripture was different.

Comment: May we should exempt this rule or logic to Hinduism as we should rely only on authentic Scriptures. BTW, can you guess why  [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10269/3500) is downvoted? Is this the same reason you mentioned? (Just wanted to know the reason).

Comment: @AnilKumar I don't find anything wrong with that Q. The person might have downvoted for other reasons. BTW, the site rules suggest the answered to be backed up with scriptures, not to copy paste them with few lines. My above answer points that part.

Comment: @iammilind What answer were you referring?

Comment: @iammilind I might not stop asking questions entirely because i'm curious and i want to learn more.But surely i'll give no importance to the voting system from here on simply because it don't deserve any.In future you'll never find posts like this one asking for reasons for down votes from me.This much is almost certain.

Comment: @AnilKumar I don't get your query. But what I meant that in my above answer I try to point that, scriptures are for backing up & not everything. Nonetheless I didn't find your answer deserving downvote. In no way I can judge it either. :-)

Comment: @Rickross You're not in the wrong place at all.  Asking for the scriptural basis for something is absolutely on-topic here.  Tons of my questions start with the words "what scriptures": http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=Is%3Aquestion+"what+scriptures"+user%3A36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes exactly, most of ur questions begin with "What scriptures?" haha..so then how can my question is equivalent to asking nothing??this has left me puzzled.I think its important to bring such questions to limelight so that ordinary human beings(like me) who does not have much command over scriptures get to know about the right way of living life.So if questions like those get downvoted it dampens the spirit of the questioner.